# Why are fibreglass type base antennas seemingly more susceptible to lightning strike?

Tags: antenna-construction

Fibreglass antennas with the radiator inside are apparently more prone to lightning strikes. Is this true, and is there a scientific reason as to why?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include some quotes from whatever sources you found this claim in?

Comment: Kevin Reid, I cannot provide a literary source. The origins of which I base my question are colloquial.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on claims that are surprised and can't be sourced.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard the rumors that fiberglass antennas attract lightning.  The theory is that the wind blowing across the fiberglass generates a static charge that attracts the lightning.  However, there is not any real evidence of this.

An alternate theory is that they do not attract lightning, but lightning strikes cause a air pressure shock wave (which is obvious, that's what causes thunder), and the shock wave from strikes that are merely near by can physically shatter the fiberglass.  (Or, as I heard described, causing the remnants of the vertical antenna to become "horizontally polarized" on the surface of the roof.)

As far as I know, neither of these alternatives have been seriously studied either for statistics of occurrence or tests for actual cause.

Comment: I've read something about the corona effect, must find that article again. Then there's the possibility of a static build up, like you say with the outer material with friction from the wind and, I'll add, nearby precipitation. However, what if it were capacitance related? We have a dielectric and a wire inside.

Comment: I think for a capacitance effect, you'd need two wires, like a shield and a center conductor.  And then the charge would be contained anyway.  I can't see this having any   effect on lightning either way.  And if it did, all those insulated wires out there would also have issues.

Comment: The other plate for a capacitive effect, if you will, is the atmosphere. Humidity, precipitation.

Comment: @FrancisArchibald but that's not how that works. Your high potential difference is between ground and "the clouds". Whether of these hundreds of meters a few millimeters are of a slightly higher $\varepsilon_r$ material than air *really* makes no difference. And if you, for some reason that is incompatible with the idea of lightning strikes, consider the wet air around the mast to be one side of the electrode, and the conductor inside the mast the other: then a properly painted mast, utility pole or tree would have *waaaay* higher capacitance than a fiiberglass-enclosed mast:thinner dielectric

Comment: @FrancisArchibald in essence, we can play the "but I can come up with a reason" game for a long time, but it really won't help us get to the truth. I'd like you to consider [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) here: the claim that one type of mast is special and gets struck be lightning more often is *a special assumption that needs to be justified through verifiable observation or reasoning from first principles; if it can't be, it shall be assumed wrong*: Find the way to explain reality with the least amount of surprising assumptions!

Comment: And to me, fiberglass somehow "attracting" lighting sounds way less likely than that this is yet another wrong urban myth about lightning, [of which many abound](https://www.weather.gov/safety/lightning-myths). For unsurprising reasons, a phenomenon that spells danger to live and property "out of thin air", is hard or impossible to mitigate and physically not trivial to understand attracts storytelling, both to give reasons and a glimpse of hope. And, honestly, hams are among the most endangered target group when it comes to "dangerous half-knowledge"; much of ham knowledge is codified hearsay

Comment: … and while that makes for a good base of operators, it can also lead to pretty surprising misconceptions being surprisingly stubborn to correct! I think you hit a point where a loud thought ("I think we should look into whether mast material makes a difference to lightning…") became a rumor ("I heard at a professional meeting that new materials for masts are relevant to lightning") to a perceived fact.

Comment: Marcus: I agree.  My point in answering was to document the rumor and its more likely alternative and underline that it is a (very common) rumor rather than to just close this unaddressed.  I've heard tower climbers swear that fiberglass antennas attract lightning, but never had anyone come up with any evidence.